# How can I use a Button to turn string values, inserted into a GUI, into variables that can be used by other functions?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following GUI and i would like to turn what i write into the "Entry" area in a variable so that I can use it for other functions.

```
top = Tk()    
top.geometry("450x300")   
     
Dog = Label(top, text = "Dog").place(x = 40, y = 70)  
Owner = Label(top, text = "Owner ").place(x = 40, y = 100)      

Dog_input_area = Entry(top, width = 30).place(x = 150, y = 70)     
Owner_input_area = Entry(top, width = 30).place(x = 150, y = 100)   

Submit = Button(top, text = "Submit").place(x = 40, y = 190) 
      
top.mainloop()
```

I think I am missing something within the Submit variable, but I am not able to understand what.

I would also like to point out that if `textvariable=input("Dog")`is inserted into the Button, I only have the option to insert data on the IDE, which is not really useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a function when the button is clicked using the `command` parameter:

```
dog_name = ""
owner_name = ""

def read_entries():
    global dog_name, owner_name
    dog_name = Dog_input_area.get()
    owner_name = Owner_input_area.get()

Button(top, text="Submit", command=read_entries).place(x=40, y=190)
```

Then, read [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) to understand why your `Dog_input_area` and `Owner_input_area` is currently `None`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you had asked or what you're trying to do, there's a way you can get everything that was entered into the entry field using this code:

```
msg_in_entry = Dog_input_area.get()  # gets whatever the user wrote
```

Then, you can also empty the entry field using this code:

```
Dog_input_area.delete(0, END)  # deletes everything in the entry field
```

I want you to also notice that variables in Python are supposed to be written with lower case letters. Which means that "Dog_input_area" is supposed to be called as "dog_input_area".
It won't crash your program but it surely is an important thing to notice among the programmers community.